# Gtk.Switch.get_active() strange working

Tags: gtk, pygtk, uiswitch

I'm confused about the **state ON/OFF of my Gtk.Switch**, I'll explain you the reason.

This is the **ON state**:

[image: switch OFF state]

```
if __name == '__main__':

    logging_file = None
    my_logger = logging.getLogger()
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    builder.get_object('switch1').connect('button-press-event', self.switching)
    builder.get_object('switch1').set_active(False)
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.printing, args=(self.__builder.get_object('switch1'),))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()


def printing(self, widget):

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print '%s is %s' % (widget.get_name(), str(widget.get_active())) 
        -------- it prints correctly True if the switch is set ON --------


def switching(self, widget):

    if logging_file is None:
        logging_file = 'log' + '_' + time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y_%X")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.logging_file, 'w')
        file_handler.setFormatter(self.__formatter)
        my_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    my_logger.info('%s is %s' % (widget.get_name(), str(widget.get_active()))) 
    -------- it prints False if the switch is set ON***, i don't know why --------
```

See the comments among the code, **the switch is on a different state if i call get_active() inside his own function handler or if i call get_active() from an external function**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I told you not to use `button-press-event` in [that other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612382/gtk-switch-doesnt-run-on-activate-signal). Use `notify::active`. When you handle `button-press-event`, your signal handler runs at a point *before* the switch has had a chance to handle that signal, so it doesn't know that it's about to change state; it only changes *after* your `switching()` handler runs, which is why you get the wrong value in `switching()`.

Comment: thank you very much, you're answering to my questions from some time :)